# Mark bevel edges after solidify

Tags: modeling

I have a profile that I want to solidify and then bevel. I'd like to mark which edges to bevel after the solidify without collapsing the stack. Is that possible in Blender?

Best,
JD[image]

Comment: I'm not sure you can. I guess you don't want to bevel the vertex itself with a shift ctrl B?

Comment: Yes, go to Object Mode and apply your solidify to your mesh, then you can use bevel modifier on all edges.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the hardsurface nerds will refute but I don't think you can. So I guess the solution is to select your vertex and to bevel it with a <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply. What I was looking for is to control the mesh after the solidify modifier. Also, the issue happens when you extrude two meeting faces, that form a concave angle, not at the corner of one face. I hope I'm clear...

Comment: maybe show more pictures because it's not clear to me

Answer (score 0):

It is possible:

1. assign the vertices you want beveled to a vertex group;
2. add Bevel modifier and in its options:
3. select Only Vertices and Limit Method: Vertex Group, then point to the group from pt1
4. add Solidify

Answer (score 0):

You can select the vertices and add them to a vertex group. Then use the bevel modifier only on that vertex group.
If the Bevel modifier is in 'Edge' mode and it's after the Solidify modifier then it will really be beveling the edge that comes from those vertices
[image]

If you have a concave turn after another (Or convex), you'll need to separate them with another vertex in the middle so the edge that connects them doesn't confuse the modifier
[image]